# Is $(0,1]$ open and closed in the set $A := (0,1] \cup \{2\}$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Observe the following example given in my textbook for a class on *metric spaces*. This example is found in the chapter titled *The Relative Metric*:

> $A := (0,1] \cup \{2\}$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then, $(0,1]$ is open in $A$ and $\{2\}$ is both open and closed in $A$.

After doing a few exercises following this given example, I begin to ask the following question:

$\bullet$ Is $(0,1]$ open and closed in the set $A := (0,1] \cup \{2\}$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$?

As the author stated, this set is open in $A$. However, upon inspecting if this set is indeed also closed, I recalled the following: If $G \subset A \subset M$, $G$ is open in $A$ if and only if $G$ is open in $M$.

Now if we let $G := (0,1]$, $A$ be the set already defined, and $M = \mathbb{R}$: isn't the set $G$ neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$? So, by the above bi-implication, how could $G$ be open in $A$ in the first place, let alone be open and closed in $A$?

Comment: 1. $(0,1]$ is open and closed in $A$ but *neither* closed *nor* open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Can you explain how it is closed in $A$? @Physor

Comment: You statement $G \subset A$ is open in A iff it is open in $M$ (when $A$ is a subspace of $M$) is true when $A$ itself is open in $M$

Comment: $(0,1]$ is closed in the subspace $A$ as $(0,1] = [0,1]\cap A$ and $[0,1]$ is closed in the total space $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you @HennoBrandsma - just what the topology doctor ordered. That alone cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Openness is something relative. For example, $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but neither closed nor open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Another example is the every space is closed and open with respect to itself.

One needs to know several definitions to understand what is meant by open and closed sets,

- open ball
- limit point of a set
- closed set
- interior point
- open set

For your question, every point in (0,1] has an open ball *which intersection with $A$*  lies completely in $A$, even if you take the pont $x = 1$. By the way the set $A$ is also not connected

Comment: @MathQED yes correct, I'll change it

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I understand what you have written, but this still doesn't address why $(0,1]$ is closed in $A$. @Physor

Comment: every point in (0,1] has an open ball *which intersection with $A$*  lies completely in $A$, even if you take the pont $x = 1$. By the way the set $A$ is also not connected

Comment: Gotcha... one more thing: considering what you just said, isn't a set closed when it contains all its limit points? $0$ is not in the set (and is a limit point i'm pretty sure?). @Physor

Comment: a set is closed when it contains all its limit points, right. In your example $0$ is a limit point of $(0,1]$, but a limit point of a set needs not be in the set

Answer (score 1):

You should have seen in your course that in a metric space, an open ball is an open subset and a closed ball is a closed subset.

In your $A$, $(0,1]$ is open because it is equal to the open ball (of $A$) $B(1/2,1)$ for instance. And it is also closed in $A$ because it is the closed ball of $A$ $\bar{B}(1/2,1)$.

Comment: How can we have a ball, open or closed, centered at $0$ if $0$ is not in $A$?

Comment: I wanted to write something easy but it is false, sorry ! I change it

Comment: So while $0$ (a limit point) is not in the set $A$, $0 \in B(1/2,1) \subseteq A$? Correct me if i'm wrong, I'm just confused on how a set is closed but does not contain all its limit points.

Comment: Here it is the ball inside $A$ : $B(1/2,1)=\{ x \in A | d(x,1/2)<1 \}$, we just look at element already in $A$, so $0$ is not in the ball. Often we write $B_A(1/2,1)$ to say we look at a ball of $A$